# Java: handle special character in URI

Tags: java, url-encoding

I am trying to access a file from URI, unfortunately, that file path contain special name.

> For example: file://C:/6-6+hf.1-181/db/mssql-ddl.sql

In detail, below is my code (scriptFile has above value):

```
File tempFile = FileUtility.fileFromUri(new URI(scriptFile));
```

Which fileFromUri function is

```
public static File fileFromUri(URI uri) {
    try {
        if(uri.getScheme() == null) {
            uri = (new File(uri.getPath())).toURI();
        } else if(!uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
            return null;
        }

        String fileName = uri.toURL().getFile();
        return new File(URLDecoder.decode(fileName, "UTF8"));
    } catch (Exception var2) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have exception like this

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/6-6+hf.1-181/db/mssql-ddl.sql
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_65]     at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:72)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_65]     at
>   com.automic.actions.common.utils.FileUtility.readFileAsString(FileUtility.java:70)
>   ~[common-tool-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]     at
>   com.automic.actions.database.utils.SQLRunner.readStatementsFromFile(SQLRunner.java:117)
>   ~[classes/:?]     at
>   com.automic.actions.database.utils.SQLRunner.executeScript(SQLRunner.java:91)
>   [classes/:?]  at
>   com.automic.actions.database.SQLFeature.run(SQLFeature.java:302)
>   [classes/:?]  at
>   com.automic.actions.common.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:24)
>   [common-tool-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]  at
>   com.automic.actions.runner.DatabaseToolFileCmd.main(DatabaseToolFileCmd.java:25)
>   [classes/:?]

I know that this exception is because I have used URLDecoder before, and after decode, Java translate '+' character to become space character. The solution may be just replace '+' character with others and then replace it later. However, I don't want to use that approach.
So can you help me with other solution for this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: so you have an uri that's not encoded properly in the first place, and then you decode it and have issues. Either you need to encode it properly on the sender (recommended) or you have to tweak decoding (not recommended).

Comment: Stupid I am, just realize that I forgot encode it before decode on function. I edited it and it work correctly.
Shame on me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass the path through URI, you should encode it first, if you use ajax, maybe `encodeURIComponent()` method is proper.
like this:

```
encodeURIComponent("file://C:/6-6+hf.1-181/db/mssql-ddl.sql")
//output
"file%3A%2F%2FC%3A%2F6-6%2Bhf.1-181%2Fdb%2Fmssql-ddl.sql"
```

if you use java `URLEncode.encode(String str, String env)` method is proper.

```
    String path = "file://C:/6-6+hf.1-181/db/mssql-ddl.sql";
    String path1 = URLEncoder.encode(path,"UTF-8");
    System.out.println(path1);
    String path2 = URLDecoder.decode(path1,"UTF-8");
    System.out.println(path2);

    //output
    file%3A%2F%2FC%3A%2F6-6%2Bhf.1-181%2Fdb%2Fmssql-ddl.sql
    file://C:/6-6+hf.1-181/db/mssql-ddl.sql
```